# Aprendiendo App Cordova

Tags: php, javascript, phonegap

Estoy empezando a aprender a programar en cordova y necesito un par de cosas:
- Conocéis alguna guía para aprender?
- Tengo el Siguiente código y cuando lo compilo con cordova run browser funciona perfectamente pero luego cuando lo pongo en el móvil al pulsar el boton no hace nada. Pueden darme un poco de ayuda o decirme donde encontrarla

Usuario NUEVO
                        
                
                
                        Password NUEVO
                        
                
                
                        
                 
                
                        Submit Funciona APP

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#loginButton2").click(function(mievento){
                    alert("Form Submitted");
            var url = "http://127.0.0.1/cordova/prueba_base/www/conectamos.php";
            var tusua = $("#useri").val(); 
            var tpass = $("#password").val(); 
            var dataString="tusuas="+tusua+"&tpasss="+tpass;
            $.getJSON(url, dataString, function(result) {
                $.each(result, function(i, field) {
                    var id = field.nombre;
                    var title = field.direccion;
                    var duration = field.telefono;
                    var price = field.movil;
                    if(id=="success")
                    {
                            localStorage.setItem("usuar", tusua);
                            localStorage.setItem("passi", tpass);
                            window.location.href = "clientes.html";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            $("#datos").append(id);
                            $("#useri").val('');
                            $("#password").val('');
                    }
              });
            });
         }); //loginButton2

         $('#infoForm').submit(function() {

                var postTo = "http://127.0.0.1/cordova/prueba_base/www/conectamos.php";

                $.get(postTo,({tusuas: $('[name=useri]').val(), tpasss: $('[name=password]').val()}),
                function(data) {

                    $.each(data, function(i, field) {
                    var id = field.nombre; 
                    var title = field.direccion;
                    var duration = field.telefono;
                    var price = field.movil;
                    if(id=="success")
                    {
                            alert('succes');
                            tusua=$('[name=useri]').val();
                            tpass=$('[name=password]').val();

                            localStorage.setItem("usuar", tusua);
                            localStorage.setItem("passi", tpass);
                            window.location.href = "clientes.html";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            $("#datos").append(id);
                            $("#useri").val('');
                            $("#password").val('');
                    }
                    });
                },'json');
                return false;
            });
</script>
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Ya he encontrado la solución, el problema es que no ponia bien la IP. Yo ponia la de "localhost" y hay que poner la que te da ipconfig o ifconfig.
Gracias.